# JavaScript Sort an Array, but keep a second array in sync

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, synchronization

I am trying to sort one array, but have a second array stay in sync with the first.

Example:

```
var a1 = ["human", "animal", "plant"];
var a2 = ["person", "beast", "nature"];

a1.sort();
```

After the sort I need to arrays to look like this:

```
a1 = ["animal", "human", "plant"];
a2 = ["beast", "person", "nature"];
```

Is there an easy way to do this, Maybe using a custom sort function?

Comment: Having two parallel arrays for your data is a bad idea. Use an array of objects `[{name: 'human', type: 'person'}, {name: 'animal', type: 'beast'}]` and you don't have to worry about syncing. If you have to sync structures, you're not following the DRY principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could zip the arrays before sorting, and unzip them after sorting:

```
var a = ["human", "animal", "plant"],
    b = ["person", "beast", "nature"],
    zipped = [];

// zip
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    zipped.push({a: a[i], b: b[i]});
}

zipped.sort(function (x, y)
{
    return x.a - y.a;
});

// unzip
var z;
for (i=0; i<zipped.length; i++)
{
    z = zipped[i];
    a[i] = z.a;
    b[i] = z.b;
}
```

...but I think @duffymo's got a better suggestion for you. Use an object/hash/associative array/map.

```
var a = [{key: 'human',  value: 'person'},
         {key: 'animal', value: 'beast'},
         {key: 'plant',  value: 'nature'}];

a.sort(function (x, y)
{
    return x.key - y.key;
});
```

Comment: Zipping the array worked perfectly! I would have never thought to do something like that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Simple, but genius!

Comment: In the first code block the line `return x.a - y.a;` should be `return x.a > y.a;` In the second block the line `return x.key - y.key;` should be `return x.key > y.key;`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this (untested):

```
a1.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {

        // swap a2[0] and a2[1]
        var tmp = a2[0];
        a2[0] = a2[1];
        a2[1] = tmp;

        return 1
    } else if (a < b) {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
});
```

## [Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fzpAh/1/)

Something like that, play around with the return values to get it perfect

Comment: Having a sort function modify a global array just sounds wrong... But I'm afraid this is the simplest way to do what OP asked for

Comment: it seems to me that this method is based on assumptions about the actual implementation of `Array.sort` code that are wrong in general: you must not assume the indices of the two items currently compared are `0` and `1`. Have a look at his modification of your sample: [modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y6Lwfog8/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an associative array and sort the keys.  That's what you've got here.  I think an associative array is a better encapsulation of the idea.